# Segmentation fault on specific memory address

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl

I have one of the most annoying problems in my opinion, called a segmentation fault. Usually with a bit of help from gdb and tracing all my code, I manage to solve these problems. Unfortunately, not this time. Since my code is kind of complex, I will show snippets relevant to the problem.

First of all, the error is given on this setter function:

```
void Texture::setRenderer( SDL_Renderer* renderer ) {
    m_renderer = renderer;
}
```

Ofcourse, in my texture class there is a variable defined as followed:

```
SDL_Renderer* m_renderer = nullptr;
```

Because of the type of error, I tried tracing the specific memory address, to see if it is valid. So, the parameter. It comes from my resource manager class, which is trying to add a texture to a map. Specific code:

```
bool ResourceManager::add( const std::string texture ) {
    Texture* tex;
    tex->setRenderer(m_renderer);
}
```

Ofcourse, also this variable (`m_renderer`) comes from a different location. My `Game` class.

```
m_resources.setRenderer(m_renderer);
```

This function is called immediately after I initialize the renderer, without any errors. So there my trace ends, without finding the problem...

I have also tried printing the memory address in all of these functions. They all print exactly the same memory address.
Stacktrace from gdb:

```
Thread 1 "ConceptGame" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000408868 in Texture::setRenderer (this=0x0, renderer=0x660b60)
at ../Texture.cpp:68
68      m_renderer = renderer;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000408868 in Texture::setRenderer (this=0x0, renderer=0x660b60)
at ../Texture.cpp:68
#1  0x0000000000406865 in ResourceManager::add (this=0x7fffffffdb50, 
texture="penguin.png") at ../ResourceManager.cpp:31
#2  0x0000000000403fb1 in Game::run (this=0x7fffffffdae0) at ../Game.cpp:83
#3  0x0000000000408b5f in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcb8) at ../main.cpp:50
```

Any help on fixing this problem is much appreciated...

Comment: When gdb does not help, it's probably time to try running your code with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: `Texture* tex;
    tex->setRenderer(m_renderer);` Is this actual code? `tex` is uninitialized here

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I just solved this indeed according to AndyG's comment...
While trying to fix this I accidentally didn't initialize the pointer, thus causing this problem.

Fixed by initializing the pointer;

```
Texture* tex = new Texture;
tex->setRenderer(m_renderer);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably need to assign that `Texture` to something more permanent than a local variable. Right now it looks like you allocate, assign to it, and then throw it away. This leaks and doesn't look all that useful in the long run.

Comment: This texture is put in a std::map on a different location. When the destructor is called of the class containing that map, I loop through the map, deleting all pointers and setting them to null. That should be okay right?